# selecting a column sorted by count but without the count

Tags: sql, sqlite

table is like this, say it represents various types of events in a log file

```
<type> <date>
```

I want to select the top 5 most common types

```
select type,count(type) as c from log order by c desc limit 5
```

this works fine, but I only want the type column so I can use this is a `where in` subquery. How do I do that? I cant work out how to supress the count colum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty straightforward:

```
SELECT type FROM log GROUP BY type ORDER BY COUNT(type) DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: I had tried that , my db (sqlite) says "misuse of aggregate count()"

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the RDBMS and this is highly dependent on which one you're using. Here are some options.

```
-- works in postgres and mysql
select type from log group by type order by count(*) desc limit 5;

-- this variant works in mssql but probably no where else (maybe sybase)
select top(5) type from log group by type order by count(*) desc;

-- works in posgres and mssqlserver but not mysql or oracle
select
      type
  from (select
        type,
        row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as r
    from
        log
    group by
        type
  ) as t
  where
    r <= 5
;

-- portable to all standards compliant RDMS
select
      type
  from (select
        type,
        row_number() over (order by c) as r
    from
        (select
                type,
                count(*) as c
            from
                log
            group by
                type
        ) as t
  ) as t
  where
    r <= 5
;

-- works if you don't have windowing functions, but returns more than 5 rows
select
        type
    from
        (select
                type,
                count(*) as c
            from
                log
            group by
                type
        ) as t
    order by
        c desc
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make this a subquery too:

```
SELECT TYPE
FROM LOG
WHERE TYPE IN
    (select type,count(type) as c 
     from log 
     order by c desc limit 5)
```

Comment: Yup exactly, I'll edit to show your query for clarity

Answer (score 0):

not used sqlite, but I'd write something like this in SQL server; maybe there's some idea you could steal?

```
select top (5) type from log group by type order by count(type) desc
```